# Calculating the potential outside a system of concentric sphere

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, potential

Let's say that there are 3 concentric spheres of radius $a$, $b$ and $c$ where $a<b<c$.  I also know that the potential on radius $a$ is 0, $b$ is A (which is a constant), $c$ is also 0.

It's obvious that it is possible to figure out the potential for all regions with radius ${}< c$.  However, is there enough information to figure out the potential outside the 3rd sphere?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Try to find the potential inside, on and outside a spherical surface of radius $\:R\:$ with total charge $\:Q\:$ uniformly distributed on it. Note that the surface charge density would be
\begin{equation}
\sigma=\dfrac{Q}{4\pi R^{2}}
\tag{01}
\end{equation}
(The simplicity of the result is inversely proportional to the difficulty of its derivation without Gauss Law. Moreover, this result will help us to find at once the potential inside and outside a ball with uniform volume charge density).

Then solve your exercise with 3 spheres.